# Error (CS0120): An object reference is required for the method

Tags: c#, grasshopper

With the code below I get the following error, the method used is documented [**here**](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/). Why is the method not accepting my list of strings to create new layers?

```
Error (CS0120): An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(string, System.Drawing.Color)' (line 73)
```

Code:

```
  private void RunScript(List<string> x, ref object A)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count;i++)
    {
      Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(x[i], Color.Black);
    }
    A = x;
  }
```

Line 73 is this one:

```
Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(x[i], Color.Black);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change it to

```
Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(x[i], ref Color.Black);
```

Note the `ref` before last  parameter.

**EDIT**

To resolve this issue you may do something like this ;

```
 object ob = Color.Black; //box value
 Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(x[i], ref ob );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the new set of errors that I get: `            
0. Error (CS0206): A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter (line 72)
1. Error (CS1502): The best overloaded method match for 'Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(string, System.Drawing.Color)' has some invalid arguments (line 72)
2. Error (CS1615): Argument 2 should not be passed with the 'ref' keyword (line 72)`

Answer (score 1):

Use ref as @Tigran suggested.

Also,

- make sure x is not null
- make sure that all strings in x are valid (not null)
- Use `<` rather than `<=` in your loop. As it stands it will try to access one item beyond the end of the list and will thrown an index out of range exception.

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked all that but still got the errors that i pasted in @Tigran's comments

Answer (score 1):

The method signature in the [documentation](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/?topic=html/M_Rhino_DocObjects_Tables_LayerTable_Add_2.htm) is:

```
public int Add(
    string layerName,
    Color layerColor
);
```

This is not a static method. You need to call it on an actual `LayerTable` object, such as in the example in the documentation:

```
partial class Examples
{
    public static Rhino.Commands.Result AddLayer(Rhino.RhinoDoc doc)
    {
        // <snip>
        layer_index = doc.Layers.Add(layer_name, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        // <snip>
    }
}
```

In the above example, `doc.Layers` returns a `LayerTable` object that you call `Add` on.

Comment: Thank you very much T.C. but how do I then relate `layer_index` to the list of string x which I define as input? I have tried the following:    `layer_index = doc.Layers.Add(layer_name, System.Drawing.Color.Black);

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Count;i++)
    {
      layer_index.Add(x[i], Color.Black);
    }`
but got the error: `The name 'layer_index' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: `layer_index` and `layer_name` are variables used in their code example, and have nothing to do with your code, and you shouldn't copy those. The point is that you have to call `Add` on *some* `LayerTable` object. For example, if you have a `RhinoDoc` object (like `doc` in the example), then you'd call something like `doc.Layers.Add(x[i], Color.Black)`. But there's not much context to what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Just add static after private.

```
private static void RunScript(List<string> x, ref object A)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count;i++)
    {
      Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTable.Add(x[i], Color.Black);
    }
    A = x;
  }
```